# thymeleaf th:inline="javascript" list mix with variable jquery

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I'm using jquery and thymeleaf. I have this code which works fine:

```
var user = /*[[${test.sparten[0].abteilung[0].datum}]]*/;
```

But I need it like this:

```
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var user = /*[[${test.sparten[one].abteilung[two].datum}]]*/;
```

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax how to mix the code? or is it not possible to do it that way?

I also tried it with

```
 var user = /*[[${test.sparten['+ one +'].abteilung['+two+'].datum}]]*/;
```

Also does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thymeleaf is a server side rendering template. If you have something set in the server then you can use `${test.sparten[__${one}__].abteilung[__${two}__].datum}`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it that way.

Thymeleaf just parses templates, so all the javascript code is treated like a plain text. Thymeleaf has no knowledge of javascript's variables and code meaning. It can evaluate variables that were added to the model in a server side.

This leads to two possible solutions:

1. You can provide variables `one` and `two` for thymeleaf in the backend controller, just like you shared the `test` object.
2. You can evaluate var which contains broader object's graph and then select needed piece using javascript.

   ```
   var one = 1;
   var two = 2;
   var sparten = /*[[${test.sparten}]]*/;
   var user = sparten[one].abteilung[two].datum
   ```